# CruiseControl.Net build logs not showing on CCNet website after upgrade

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We've been using CruiseControl.Net for a couple of years now and it has been working fine. However, since our last upgrade a few weeks ago to the latest version (1.5.0.6237) our build reports are failing to display on the ccnet website. Instead we get the following message:

> ```
> "BUILD FAILED
> Project: TX
> Date of build: 2010-06-22 23:41:54
> Running time: 00:05:06
> Integration Request: Build (ForceBuild) triggered from ScheduleTrigger
> Last changed: 2010-06-22 15:14:14
> Last log entry: Merge Branches:
> Origin=$/Source/RE/Branches/3.1
> Version: 2629 [DT-  3652]: Reporting:
> Capture tradable duration seperately
> Modifications since last build (10)
> Checked in Donald.sutherland Trunk/SLP/SLPDatabase/CreateScripts/CreateReportDataStoreTables.sql
> Merge Branches: Origin=$/Source/RE/Branches/3.1
> Version: 2629 [DT-3652]: Reporting:
> Capture tradable duration seperately
> 2010-06-22 15:14:14
> Checked in Donald.sutherland Trunk/SLP/SLPDatabase/Change Scripts/ReportDataStore/RpDataStoreDatabaseChangeScript.sql
> Merge Branches: Origin=$/Source/RE/Branches/3.1
> Version: 2629 [DT-3652]: Reporting:
> Capture tradable duration seperate
> ```

What should follow is a number of error messsages indicating why the build has failed. The webpage that is failing to parse the log file is "ViewBuildReport.aspx". In order to get an explanation, our development team has to go through the full Build Log xml and search for failures.

The build.config file is attached below:

```
<project name="TX" queue="Build" queuePriority="1400">
 <triggers>
  <scheduleTrigger time="21:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
   <weekDays>
    <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Saturday</weekDay>
    <weekDay>Sunday</weekDay>
   </weekDays>
  </scheduleTrigger>
 </triggers>
 <sourcecontrol type="vault" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
  <executable>c:\program files\sourcegear\vault client\vault.exe</executable>
  <username>build</username>
  <password>*********</password>
  <host>niddrie.dataexplorers.net:8080</host>
  <repository>DXL Source</repository>
  <folder>$/Source/TX/Trunk</folder>
  <ssl>false</ssl>
  <useWorkingDirectory>true</useWorkingDirectory>
  <workingDirectory>D:\Projects\Source\TX\Trunk</workingDirectory>
  <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
  <timeout units="minutes">30</timeout>
 </sourcecontrol>
 <tasks>
  <msbuild>
   <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
   <workingDirectory>D:\Projects\Source\TX\Trunk</workingDirectory>
   <projectFile>TransactionExplorer.sln</projectFile>
   <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release /v:diag</buildArgs>
   <targets>Build</targets>
   <timeout>600</timeout>
   <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
  </msbuild>
  <exec>
   <executable>deploy.bat</executable>
   <baseDirectory>D:\Projects\Source\TX\Trunk</baseDirectory>
   <buildArgs>D:\Projects\Source\TX\Trunk D:\MasterWebsite\SfsWebroot\Autobuild\TX</buildArgs>
   <buildTimeoutSeconds>500</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </exec>
 </tasks>
 <publishers>
  <!-- Mandatory, config file does not work without -->
  <xmllogger logDir="C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\TX\Artifacts\buildlogs" />
  &email;
 </publishers>
</project>
```

As you can see, there is a publisher and the config file hasn't changed since we upgraded to the latest CruiseControl Version. Finally, the necessary log files get generated during the build so it seems to be an issue with the xsd parse or the website itself? The build result files generated are listed below:

1. C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\TX\Artifacts\msbuild-results.xml
2. C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\TX\Artifacts\buildlogs\log20100622234154.xml

Any help to get this working will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your email publisher? There have been a breaking change with CCNET 1.5. You can read more here :

- http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/CCNet%201.5%20CTP%20Release%20Notes.html
- http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Email%20Publisher.html

If I understood you well, you said that your build worked fine but since you upgraded it fails, isn't it? How did you do the upgrade? Did you change directory/rights?

Comment: Hi Benjamin,thanks for your reply. We finally used a custom xslt to parse the results. It seemed that the upgrade came with a broken xslt and therefore we couldn't clearly review the build results.